# Errors right after creating Spring Boot Application in IntelliJ

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-14

After creating the Spring Boot application in IntelliJ IDEA, it has errors. I didn't edit the code. It can't find org.spring.boot.SpringApplication. I've tried to create the app several times but no effect. All needed plugins are in the IDE, switched on. Maybe someone already had the problem

[Errors in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnLJG.png)

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

[Errors in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHJOF.png)

```
Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.4.4
Cannot resolve jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:1.3.5
Cannot resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.4
Cannot resolve org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.7.1
Cannot resolve com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.4
Cannot resolve jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.3
Cannot resolve org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:9.0.44
Cannot resolve com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.4
Cannot resolve org.glassfish:jakarta.el:3.0.3
Cannot resolve org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:5.4.5
Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:2.4.4
Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-aspects:5.3.5
Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-web:5.3.5
```

Comment: Right click on the pom.xml and select Maven -> Reload Project

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Great. I added my comment as the answer if you like to accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the pom.xml and select Maven -> Reload Project